# Small signal gain

Tags: mosfet, gain, pmos, small-signal

I'm struggling to find the small signal gain of the circuit shown below. I am trying to find the gain from Vout to Va. Note that Vout corresponds to the output of an amplifier. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: you could start by identifying what configuration it is, and finding the typical gain for that configuration.

Comment: Whats confusing is that when I do the small signal analysis the output is not at the drain like it typically is in a CS amp. Unfortunately using the typical configuration does not work when trying to identify the poles and zeros.

Comment: That's right; it's not a CS amp, it's a common drain amp, aka source follower.